# Making TeXworks use tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, texworks, linux, debian

I need to create a document (I am using TeXworks) that requires the following packages/libraries:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,babel}
```

I can compile it using TeXworks under Windows but whenever I try to do it under Debian Wheezy I get this error message:

> ! I can't find file `tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex'. <argument> ...nput
>   tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
>                                                     \catcode`\@ =\csname tikz... l.8 \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,babel}

What is the easiest way to make it work?

I understand I should be able to put some libraries/packages in the same directory my .tex file is and make it work, but I can't. I have downloaded tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex and put it in the directory but then the error message I get is this one:

> (./tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex
>
> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/handle active
>   characters  in code' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you
>   misspelled it.
>
> See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation

Comment: i think you don't have tikz 3.00 installed. put `\pgfversion` to typeset the verion on the document or use `\listfiles` in the preamble and look at the log fie for the version info

Comment: My pgf version is 2.10. How should I update it?

Comment: If you want to use currently updated stuff, by far the best option is to eliminate Debian's TeX Live packages from your system and use upstream's installer to install under `/usr/local/texlive`. (It won't use directories managed by Debian's package manager. Recommendation: install and manage the upstream installation as a non-root user who isn't you e.g. as a user named `texlive` or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the TikZ library `babel` unless you have TikZ/PGF version 3.00 (or later).

Installing the new version over an older TeX Live is not recommended. Update your TeX distribution.